# Cannot join domain despite able to ping to domain to domain controller by domain name and ip

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 unable to connect to an existing domain. Previously it has successfully joined the domain and someday it appears to not join the domain anymore, when we try to unjoin to rejoin the domain, it failed. This is the error details:

> Note: This information is intended for a network administrator.  If
>   you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator
>   that you received this information, which has been recorded in the
>   file C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.
>
> DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource
>   record used to locate a domain controller for domain
>   "angkasapura1.corp":
>
> The query was for the SRV record for
>   _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.angkasapura1.corp
>
> The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
>
> adc.angkasapura1.corp
>
> bdc.angkasapura1.corp
>
> However no domain controllers could be contacted.
>
> Common causes of this error include:
>
> - Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect
>     addresses.
> - Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.

It said that it cant contact the domain controller, however it can ping to the domain controller successfully either by ip or domain name. the dns entry for adc and bdc were also present on the DNS. Is there any way we can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the firewall isn't the culprit and you haven't messed with your DNS settings, try the following:

1. Take it out from a domain joined network (as Admin, launch '**SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe**', then under 'Computer Name' tab click [Change...] and select *Workgroup* 'WORKGROUP'. 
   Click [OK] > [Close] and reboot.
2. Launch again 'SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe' as Admin > [Network ID..] > 
   *This computer is part of a business networ...* and proceed as usual.
3. Once domain rejoined, reboot again.

That's it.
Note: this probably happened due to a VM rollback or AD token got out of sync.